# Save/Set Windows SummaryInformation properties using Python 3.5

Tags: python

I have been using Tim Golden's win_filesummary.py (it's very good) with success.  I am trying to figure out how to reverse the process and set a string into the comment property.  I have all of the appropriate values => (IID('{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}'), 6), but am having difficulty figuring out how to set the comment, not just get it.

The link to Tim's file is: 
[win_filesummary.py](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-document-summary-info.html)

I cannot find anything online, so after some searching I thought I would pick the SO braintrust.

Thanks in advance.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Update:

Still investigating, and getting closer.

In short, I am attempting to copy a file (typically a jpg) to a new location and with a new name.  I then want to place the original filename into the comment section of the new file (some of the filenames have useful information).

The copy goes just fine.  I then step through the below code up to the very last statement (I found this snippet inside of a test script found at: https://github.com/kovidgoyal/pywin32/blob/master/com/win32com/test/testStorage.py):

```
def setCommentProperty(self, filepath, comment):
    try:
        m=storagecon.STGM_READWRITE | storagecon.STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE
        pss=pythoncom.StgOpenStorageEx(filepath, m, storagecon.STGFMT_FILE, 0 , pythoncom.IID_IPropertySetStorage)
        '''
        pssum=pss.Create(pythoncom.FMTID_SummaryInformation,
            pythoncom.IID_IPropertySetStorage,
            storagecon.PROPSETFLAG_DEFAULT,
            storagecon.STGM_READWRITE|storagecon.STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE)
            #storagecon.STGM_READWRITE|storagecon.STGM_CREATE|storagecon.STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE)
        '''
        pssum = pss.Open(pythoncom.FMTID_SummaryInformation, m)
        pssum.WriteMultiple([storagecon.PIDSI_COMMENTS],[comment])

        pssum=None
        pss=None    ## doesn't seem to be a close or release method, and you can't even reopen it from the same process until previous object is gone 
    except pythoncom.com_error as e:
        print (e)
        print (vars(e))
        print (e.args)
        hr,msg,exc,arg = e.args
```

=== Results ===

```
Old:f:\pictures\pythontest\dsc_0003.jpg ==> New: F:\Pictures\PythonTestTarget\2010\2010-05\TEST-2010-05-09-18-59-24.jpg
(-2147287038, 'STG_E_FILENOTFOUND', None, None) 
{'excepinfo': None,'argerror': None, 'hresult': -2147287038, 'strerror':
```

'STG_E_FILENOTFOUND'} 
    (-2147287038, 'STG_E_FILENOTFOUND', None, None)

I think this is telling me that the open function cannot find the summary information portion of the file properties.  Of course, being a jpg this does indeed exist, and I've checked the properties on the file using the explorer, and it is there.

The variable pss seems to be fine and is an PyIPropertySetStorage object.  The FMTID_SummaryInformation also appears to be correct (having checked it against Microsoft's info: pythoncom.FMTID_SummaryInformation = IID('{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}')).

The commented code above for the Create method does not return an exception, but it also doesn't create the comment string changes.

Anyone have an idea why the summary information properties are not being found?  If not that, then how do I write anything to any property so I can accomplish my goals.

Thanks in advance again,
B.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Further Update (7/22/2017):

The saga continues (and I'm still baffled):

I've narrowed down the code to a minimal script to further my search:

```
import os, sys
import pythoncom
import shutil
from win32com.shell import shell
from win32com import storagecon

if __name__ == '__main__':
    orig_filepath = "F:\Pictures\PythonTest\DSC_0003.jpg" 
    new_filepath  = "F:\Pictures\PythonTestTarget\CopiedFile.jpg" 
    comment = "This is a test comment"

try:
    destination = shutil.copy2(orig_filepath, new_filepath)

    m=storagecon.STGM_READWRITE | storagecon.STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE
    pidl, flags = shell.SHILCreateFromPath (os.path.abspath (new_filepath), 0)
    property_set_storage = shell.SHGetDesktopFolder ().BindToStorage (pidl, None, pythoncom.IID_IPropertySetStorage)
    property_storage = property_set_storage.Open (pythoncom.FMTID_SummaryInformation, m)
    property_storage.WriteMultiple([storagecon.PIDSI_COMMENTS],[comment])


except pythoncom.com_error as e:
    print (e)
    print (vars(e))
    print (e.args)
    hr,msg,exc,arg = e.args
```

The code copies a file and then attempts to add a comment to the new file copy.

The results are:

```
(-2147287035, 'Access Denied.', None, None)
{'hresult': -2147287035, 'excepinfo': None, 'strerror': 'Access Denied.', 'argerror': None}
(-2147287035, 'Access Denied.', None, None)
The thread 'MainThread' (0x2de0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[11388] python.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Does anyone have any clue what this is resulting in an 'Access Denied' exception?

Once again, thank you in advance:
B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, but not in any satisfying way.

I can now add text to a comment field in a jpeg file. This works for now, but is not as generic as I would have hoped.

The solution I found was to use the package 'piexif'.  It worked very well, and as advertised.  It is a nice tool and helped me reach my goal.

Having said that, I still am going to search out a solution to the 'access denied' problem mentioned above.  It doesn't make sense to me that a file that was copied via python, has no read-only issues, and which I am able to step through the attributes/properties/metadata with no problems would yield an 'access denied' when attempting to write to its metadata.

If any one reads this and can provide an answer, I would love to hear it.

Thanks again to everyone who read this and spent a few cycles thinking about it.

B.